# A one-liner to selectively include modules within an Android project at build-time?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project set up so that uses module system as a way to "plug-in" features selectively.

Here's what the project hierarchy looks like:

- app

  - manifests
  - java
  - assets
  - res
- module1

  - manifests
  - java
  - assets
  - res
- module2

  - manifests
  - java
  - assets
  - res
- ...

Basically what I want to do is selectively include these `module1` and `module2` so that I can decide what  module to include when building.

I already have achieved this by adding

`compile project(:module1)` to build.gradle

and setting the settings.gradle file as follows:

`include ':app', ':module1'`

But here's the real question: Honestly I don't know why I have to modify both of these files.

Technically the `build.gradle` file describes the dependency between modules, which means if I included :module1, doesn't this imply that I am including this in the build?

Is there a way to make a change to a single file, and it would take care of everything, instead of updating these two files?

Comment: Checkout different build variants (types/flavors). More under [Configure your build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html) and [Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html). It should be able to use different modules using different gradle builds. Something like `./gradlew app:assembleModule1` and `./gradlew app:assembleModule2`.

Maybe this answers your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081846/use-different-build-types-of-library-module-in-android-app-module-in-android-stu

Comment: @TimoBähr thanks, this works if you have only limited combination of modules but I'm thinking somewhat of a plugin type architecture where developers can mix and match different modules depending on what they need. I am not sure if this approach would work for this purpose..

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `settings.gradle` file dynamic, then the projects just need to be in a predictable path.  In the future to include a new project you only need to create the folder structure and add a `build.gradle` file.

```
$ cat settings.gradle

// search for directories at the same level as the `settings.gradle` file
def moduleDirs = settingsDir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    boolean accept(File pathname) {
        // if is a directory and directory contains a `build.gradle` file add to `moduleDirs` list
        return pathname.isDirectory() && pathname.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.name == 'build.gradle'
            }
        }).size() == 1
    }
})
// now that we know all the modules create a project for each
// modules will define their own relationship (in their `build.gradle`)
// here we just declare the name and location of each
for (def moduleDir : moduleDirs) {
    include ":$moduleDir.name"
    project(":$moduleDir.name").projectDir = moduleDir
}
```

Not quite a single file solution however you now don't have to touch the `settings.gradle` again.

In the future if someone wants to make a consumer they could either rely on the `jar` output of the build (ie maven repo stored jars) or add their project to the file structure.  From there they could choose what projects to depend on as usual in the `build.gradle`

`projectA/build.gradle:` Contains `projectA && projectB` but not `projectC..projectZ`

```
// ...
dependencies {
    compile project(':projectB')
}
```

`projectC/build.gradle:` Contains `projectC && projectZ` but `projectA || projectB`

```
// ...
dependencies {
    compile project(':projectZ')
}
```