# How to get Current Build Type in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My Question is very direct and easy to understand.

**Question**

In Gradle, is there any way I can get the current build type at runtime. For example, when running an assemble**Debug** task, can tasks within the build.gradle file make decisions based on the fact that this task is related to the debug build variant?

**Sample Code**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
ext.buildInProgress = "" 

buildscript {

repositories {
    maven {
        url = url_here
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
}


configurations {
     //get current build in progress here e.g buildInProgress = this.getBuildType()
}

android {
     //Android build settings here
}

buildTypes {
         release {
          //release type details here
      }

       debug {
           //debug type details here
       }

    anotherBuildType{
          //another build type details here
    }

   }
}

dependencies {
      //dependency list here
}

repositories{
         maven(url=url2_here)
}


task myTask{
      if(buildInProgress=='release'){
           //do something this way
      }
      else if(buildInProgress=='debug'){
          //do something this way
      }
      else if(buildInProgress=='anotherBuildType'){
         //do it another way
     }
}
```

**In Summary**

Is there a way for me to get exactly the build type in progress within **myTask{}**?

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm trying to solve the next task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677223/how-to-check-if-current-build-is-debug-or-release-in-build-gradle

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get the exact build type by parsing your `applicationVariants`:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    buildType = variant.buildType.name // sets the current build type
}
```

A implementation could look like the following:

```
def buildType // Your variable

android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        buildType = variant.buildType.name // Sets the current build type
    }
}

task myTask{
    // Compare buildType here
}
```

Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42839705/9647266) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36720624/9647266) similar answers.

**Update**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084099/9647266) answer by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28081846/9647266) question helped the questioner to settle the problem.

Comment: I have tried this out, but it doesn't work. buildType is null when I make the checks inside myTask

Comment: Also, it is a library project and not an application so I used 'libraryVariants.all' and not 'applicationVariants.all'

Comment: Thanks. This has saved me some stress. Been trying different methods to work around it in the last few days withouth success, not knowing its a Gradle limitation.

Comment: I'm going to update my answer later accordingly to match your question

Comment: and what `buildType` is supposed to have?  String? I tried `if (buildType == "debug")` but it returns `false`... I'm trying to solve the next task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677223/how-to-check-if-current-build-is-debug-or-release-in-build-gradle

Comment: and it's `null`: `Cannot invoke method contains() on null object`

Comment: so `buildType` is `null`

Comment: This solution is a magic trick. You're looping over _all_ build variants, assigning `buildType` multiple times, and last is/was by some coincidence correct current build type.

Comment: This is no longer working. The order of iteration is not related to the current build type.

Comment: @UnlikePluto Can you please delete or maybe add clarification that this answer is wrong?! As Peter said this is pure coincidence.

Comment: I run 'gradlew assembleDebug', and the code in {} of applicationVariants.all not invoke.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def variantType = variant.buildType.name
    println "Variant type: $variantType"
    if (variantType == "debug") {
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you execute this, in app/build.gradle?

Comment: Yes. It needs to be in app level gradle.

Comment: I run this, and I get an error: ` Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' `

Comment: I am not sure what is your app gradle looks like. I suspect it can be due to lower gradle version or you may be executing this for a library. For library use 'libraryVariants' instead of 'applicationVariants'. Gradle supports such extensions. More info here https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.html

Comment: is it possible to get the flavor name in the root level build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You should `getBuildConfigFields().get("MY_BUILD_TYPE").getValue())`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59994937/5279996

GL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suffix the buildtype name to the versionname (like me) just add this line to the version name:

```
debug {
    versionNameSuffix "-debug"
}
```

This way you can identify the build type in the build name. And it works without declaring anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way for getting the current buildType being used during build in Kotlin programming language for android platform (logic is the same for Java)

```
project.afterEvaluate {
   this.android().variants().all {

      this.assembleProvider.configure {

         this.doLast{
            val variant = this@all

            variant.outputs
                       .map
                       .forEach{
                           //do something with current buildType, or build flavor or whatever
                           println(variant.flavorName)
                           println(variant.buildType)
                       }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting build type in this way:

```
BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE
```

If you need to check what is the current build type, create an enum class in your utils package and use it in your if statement:

```
enum class Environment(val value: String) {
   RELEASE("release"),
   LOCAL("local"),
   STAGING("staging"),
   DEBUG("debug")
}
```

Your if/when statement:

```
if (BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE == Environment.RELEASE.value) {
     //TODO
} else if(...)
```

or through when:

```
when(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE) {
   Environment.RELEASE.value -> { //TODO }
   Environment.LOCAL.value -> { // TODO }
   // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked other answers, nothing works.
What's below will help.
In your build.gradle (:app):

```
tasks.all { Task task ->
    if (task.name == "preDebugBuild") {
        doFirst {
            //for debug build
        }
    } else if (task.name == "preReleaseBuild") {
        doFirst {
            //for release build
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Be aware, the code that you put inside will not be executed when you change the build variant, but when you build app.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in your gradle : It works fine for me

```
//get current build all params as string
def buildParams = getGradle().getStartParameter().toString().toLowerCase();

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        def typename = variant.buildType.name.toLowerCase();

        //and check build state in all variants
        if(buildParams.contains(typename)) {
            // finally, you get what you want.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's the approach I used to detect the runtime build type without declaring any variables at build time.

```
def isCurrentBuildType(buildType) {
  return gradle.getStartParameter().taskNames.find({ it.endsWith(buildType) }) != null
}

print(isCurrentBuildType("Release")) //prints true if the current build type is release.
```

Note that the first letter should be capital (e.g. assembleRelease, bundleRelease)

Comment: The build type is not always last. Use `.contains`,not `.endsWith`.  ex. `testDebugUnitTests`

Answer (score -3):

You can get the exact build type by parsing your applicationVariants:

`applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    buildType = variant.buildType.name // sets the current build type
}`