# Android & Gradle - Check Build Type in Product Flavor

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Currently I have an application which has 6 different variants:

- devDebug
- devRelease
- stageDebug
- stageRelease
- prodDebug
- prodRelease

My current gradle is like that:

```
signingConfigs {
        ...
        release {
            ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

productFlavors {
        ...
        dev {
            ...
        }
        stage {
            ...
        }
        prod {
            ...
        }
    }
```

I want to check Build Type in every Product Flavor. How can I do this? **But still I want to use same 6 variants.** I know that I could create new buildType but my variant number would be 9 unnecessarily, I still want to use 6 variants

What I want is something like that:

```
signingConfigs {
        ...
        release {
            ...
        }
        myNewConfig {
            ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        release {
            ...
        }
    }

productFlavors {
        ...
        dev {
            if (buildType == "release" {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        stage {
            if (buildType == "release" {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        prod {
            if (buildType == "release" {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.myNewConfig
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181684/11372697) but it didnt worked for me. My purpose is; when I use prod environment and if I want to release my app, apart from `Debug` and `Release`, I want to use `myNewConfig`, which I define differently.